# how to customize display of very long drop down list in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, rwd, phtml

I have many subcategories to be displayed in home page, but it is vertically too long,, i want to make it scroll on hover. what changes need to be done in css or other files, please guide me script which is responsive

reference:https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/
i want scolling of list as in referred website mentioned above

[image: subcategories with long dropdown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add height and overflow scroll 
styke.css line 3529

.nav-primary li.level0 ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fbfbfb;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

this `jquery` function for `dropdown scroll` adjust it according to your classes.

```
 <script>
var maxHeight = 100;
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery(".nav-primary > li").hover(function() { 

         var jQuerycontainer = jQuery(this),
             jQuerylist = jQuerycontainer.find("ul"),
             jQueryanchor = jQuerycontainer.find("a"),
             height = jQuerylist.height() * 1.1,       // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
             multiplier = height / maxHeight;     // needs to move faster if list is taller

        // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
        jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight", jQuerycontainer.height());

        // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
        jQueryanchor.addClass("hover");

        // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
        jQuerylist
            .show()
            .css({
                paddingTop: jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight")
            });

        // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
        if (multiplier > 1) {
            jQuerycontainer
                .css({
                    height: maxHeight,
                    overflow: "hidden"
                })
                .mousemove(function(e) {
                    var offset = jQuerycontainer.offset();
                    var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - (jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                    if (relativeY > jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight")) {
                        jQuerylist.css("top", -relativeY + jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight"));
                    };
                });
        }

    }, function() {

        var jQueryel = jQuery(this);

        // put things back to normal
        jQueryel
            .height(jQuery(this).data("origHeight"))
            .find("ul")
            .css({ top: 0 })
            .hide()
            .end()
            .find("a")
            .removeClass("hover");

    })});

    // Add down arrow only to menu items with submenus
    // jQuery(".nav-primary > li:has('ul')").each(function() {
    //     jQuery(this).find("a:first").append("<img src='images/down-arrow.png' />");
    // });
</script>
```

Comment: I don want to add scrolling bar through overflow scroll,, i want just to scroll on hover of subcategories or atleast just display arrows to scroll

Comment: scoll bar doesnt look good for homepage display

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/   follow this to design the scroll bar

Comment: I want something to display like this: https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/

Comment: i added js in answer  adjust the class according to it

Comment: please guide me where to add that js code in magento. provide me path where it exists

Comment: you can add in your footer.phtml

Comment: update the answer..